# Return a custom response body directly from Apache

Tags: configuration, apache-2.4

Is it possible to configure Apache to return content directly at a particular location? Without actually creating a file anywhere with that contents. Something like:

```
<location /custom-location.txt>
    <responsebody>hello world!</responsebody>
</location>
```

Comment: Aren't down-votes without comments to explain why frowned upon?

Comment: Are you wanting to originate a 200 response? What are you trying to achieve with this (eg. a maintenance curtain or similar would be better as a 503).

Comment: @CameronKerr so I need a specific URL to return a 200 response along with the word "UP". Just that. For all other URLs, Apache is proxying through to an application, but to get the application to respond to this particular URL is pretty difficult, so I was hoping I could do it simply in Apache configuration.

Comment: That sounds more like you want a monitoring URL to be excluded from your ProxyPass directive so you monitor Apache rather than both Apache and the application behind Apache... E.g. something like `ProxyPass /some/app/path/status !  # excluded from proxy directive below` and then your current config `ProxyPass /some/app http://host:port/app`  - Possibly with combined with an Alias Directive so you don't have to create the whole path

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you only have that option for [error messages](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument) i.e.:

```
ErrorDocument 404 "Sorry but the requested resource can't be found."
```